# How to prevent Excel from changing active sheet to newly created sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button to create a sheet which works. However, when I create a new sheet with the function, it relocates or redirects me to that new sheet.

I also have a delete button which accepts the sheet name and deletes it instantly with no redirection or relocating.

Is there a way to prevent the redirecting?

```vb
Option Explicit

Public sheetName As Variant

Sub AddSheet()
    On Error Resume Next
    sheetName = InputBox("New Sheet Name", "Prototype 01")
    If sheetName = "" Then
        MsgBox "Sheet name cannot be empty!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = sheetName
    MsgBox "" & sheetName & " was successfully created!"
End Sub

Sub DeleteSheet()
    On Error Resume Next
    sheetName = InputBox("Sheet Name", "Prototype 01")
    If sheetName = "" Then Exit Sub
    Sheets(sheetName).Delete
    MsgBox """" & sheetName & """ was successfully removed!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can switch sheets via Worksheet.Activate function of vba.

```
Sheets("YourSheetName").Activate
```

Once you create the new sheet, add this code to return back to your original sheet.

Answer (score 1):

### Add a Worksheet or Delete a Sheet

- It is assumed that the delete code will be called by a button so the active sheet (the one with the button) cannot accidentally be deleted.

**Add**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddSheet()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Add Sheet"
    
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
    
    Dim aws As Worksheet: Set aws = ActiveSheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = aws.Parent
    
    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = InputBox("Enter name of sheet to be ADDED", PROC_TITLE)
    If Len(SheetName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Sheet name cannot be empty!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim nws As Worksheet
    Set nws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next ' invalid or existing sheet name
        nws.Name = SheetName
        ErrNum = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim IsSuccess As Boolean
    
    If ErrNum = 0 Then
        IsSuccess = True
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            nws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    aws.Select
    
    If IsSuccess Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet """ & SheetName & """ successfully added.", _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not rename to """ & SheetName & """.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    End If

End Sub
```

**Delete**

```vb
Sub DeleteSheet()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Sheet"
    
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
    
    Dim aws As Worksheet: Set aws = ActiveSheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = aws.Parent
    
    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = InputBox("Enter name of sheet to be DELETED", PROC_TITLE)
    
    If Len(SheetName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Sheet name cannot be empty!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dsh As Object ' allowing charts to be deleted
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dsh = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error Resume Next
    
    If dsh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no sheet named """ & SheetName & """!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Don't delete the ActiveSheet, the one with the buttons.
    If dsh Is aws Then
        MsgBox "Cannot delete the 'button' worksheet """ & aws.Name & """!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' A very hidden sheet cannot be deleted. There is no error though.
    If dsh.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
        MsgBox "Cannot delete the very hidden sheet """ & SheetName & """!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        dsh.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    aws.Select
    
    MsgBox "Sheet """ & SheetName & """ successfully deleted.", _
        vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```